# NoMethodError 'route' for main:Object in Sinatra app (Ruby 2.0.0p481)

Tags: ruby, routes, localhost, sinatra, nomethoderror

I'm working on a Sinatra app (not one that I developed) in Ruby 2.0.0p481, as the title says. When I try to run the program to test my controller method, I get an undefined method 'route' error.

```
require 'sinatra'
...
route :get, :post, '/parsedresume' do
```

I know the code functions in production, but when I try to test it on my local machine, it's causing nothing but problems, and I'm not sure where to start. I think it's probably something silly and dumb that I'm forgetting, but I've exercised the full might of my google-fu and haven't found anything.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show us the program you use to test the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring is hard as hell.

`route :get, :post ...` doesn't look as Sinatra route. Usually routes in pure Sinatra application defined as `get '/' do ...` or `post '/' do ...`. Not sure about that, but such method **isn't** mentioned in Sintra [Documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html). May be is there another framework on top of Sinatra?

> I'm not sure where to start

Try to start with the following.
Reproduce production environment as precise as you can.
I mean:

1. **Ruby version as first step.** Should be same. On production Ruby may be the part of system i.e. installed via packages. You may use `rvm` or `rbenv` or etc on your dev environment. Make sure you have checked `ps auxww | grep -i ruby` output, in order to be confident that your production uses Ruby you have found before. It's not joke. System Ruby may be installed, however e.g. JRuby may be used in project...
2. **Versions of gems**. Should be the same. You are lucky of project has `Gemfile.lock`. If it doesn't, you can only rely on output of `gem list`. Try to examine dependencies of Application and install exact versions of packeges.
3. **Hardcoded** paths in Application. Sad but true. It is up to you: change them in code, or spoof on dev environment.

This is not so comprehensive answer, hope is may be good starting point for your situation. Feel free to ask more. By the way, Ruby stack trace may be very helpful.

Good luck!